# Помогите распарсить массив JSON с помощью Retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Недавно начал изучать Retrofit, вывел в консоль мой JSON через ScalarsConverter как стринг.
Сейчас пытаюсь получить обьекты.
**Вот мой JSON:**

[ ["Horoscopes accurately predict...", false],
["The National Weather Service ... ", false] ]

**Data классы:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Инициализация Ретрофит:**
interface QuestApi {

```
@GET("curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json")
fun getInfo(): Call<MainList>

companion object {

    var BASE_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/"

    fun create(): QuestApi {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory()
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(QuestApi::class.java)
```

**Получение ответа:**

val apiInterface = QuestApi.create().getInfo()

```
    apiInterface.enqueue(object : Callback<MainList> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<MainList>,
            response: retrofit2.Response<MainList>
        ) {
            Log.d("tag", response.body().toString())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<MainList>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("tag", "failure")
        }
    })
```

Получаю "failure" в логах.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь и обьяснение!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ ["Horoscopes accurately predict...", false], ["The National Weather Service ... ", false] ]`
Здесь нет объектов, от слова совсем. Это двумерный массив и парсить его нужно соответственно в двумерный массив или список:

```kotlin
@GET("curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json")
fun getInfo(): Call<List<List<Any>>>
```

```kotlin
val apiInterface = QuestApi.create().getInfo()

apiInterface.enqueue(object : Callback<List<List<Any>>> {
    override fun onResponse(
        call: Call<List<List<Any>>>,
        response: retrofit2.Response<List<List<Any>>>
    ) {
        Log.d("tag", response.body().toString())
    }

    override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<List<Any>>>, t: Throwable) {
        // так вы увидите более информативный лог
        Log.e("tag", "failure", t)
    }
})
```